# Constructor not being called while autowiring in service stack

Tags: c#, servicestack, autowired

I am writing a service in c# using a service stack framework. I have this class InMemoryFileSystem (https://gist.github.com/elixir24/9457433) that I am trying to auto wire.

Here is the relevant portion of the class

public class InMemoryFileSystem {

```
    public Dictionary<string, UserFileSystem> clientToFileSystemMap {get;set;}

    public DateTime lastcheckpoint { get; set; }

    private static readonly log4net.ILog Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(InMemoryFileSystem));

    public InMemoryFileSystem ()
    {
        clientToFileSystemMap = new Dictionary<string, UserFileSystem>();
        UserFileSystem filesystem = new UserFileSystem();
        filesystem.metadata = new UserMetaData("piyush", "password", 1);
        UserFile file = new UserFile("/x.txt","piyush");
        file.filecontent = Utils.getByteArrayFromString("Filecontent");
        filesystem.filemap.Add("/x.txt", file);
        this.clientToFileSystemMap.Add("piyush", filesystem);
    }
   }
```

The object of the class InMemoryFileSytem is getting auto wired but its data members which I initialize in its constructor are still NULL. I am suspecting that maybe its default constructor is still getting called.

Here is the code where I use the auto wiring - https://gist.github.com/elixir24/9457490

```
        public class AppHost : AppHostBase
        {   
            public AppHost() : base("Hello Web Services",typeof(CloudFileService).Assembly) { }

            public override void Configure(Funq.Container container){
                Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature());
                this.Config.DefaultContentType = "Json";    
                container.RegisterAutoWired<InMemoryFileSystem>();
            }
         }
```

Does any one have any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: I am following this link  - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container

Comment: please post your code in the question so we can help without checking another website

Comment: Done. I just added the links to reduce the clutter.

Comment: +1 it's now a good question, thank you.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the constructor do you hit it? Also where is the code for the instance of InMemoryFileSystem ?